# Detecting tab changed event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms. I need to detect the event of tab being changed either by swapping left or right or by clicking *without using custom renderer*

I tried below event but it is firing in both cases when child page being pushed or tab being changed. how can i get isolated event of *tab being changed*

```
public class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
   public MyTabbedPage()
   {
      this.CurrentPageChanged += CurrentPageHasChanged;
   }
   protected void CurrentPageHasChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
       var pages= Navigation.NavigationStack;
       if (pages.Count > 0)
       {
           this.Title = pages[pages.Count - 1].Title;
       }
       else
       this.Title = this.CurrentPage.Title;
   }
}
```

**This issue I am facing is**: In below screenshot part1 is Homepage(title="Diary") & part2 is Childpage(title="Homework") when I change tab & again come to first tab than navigationbar title getting changed "Homework" to "Diary"(Screeshot2)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't remember how exactly it works for Xamarin but try checking the `sender` and `e` in debug mode and see if there's any difference for two scenarios you've described...

Comment: `sender` having `CurrentPage` sender-->base-->base-->CurrentPage. But I am not able get that page name. This can help me.

Answer (score 11):

As you are on your tabbed page already you can literally just do the following

```
public partial class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        CurrentPageChanged += CurrentPageHasChanged;
    }

    private void CurrentPageHasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => Title = CurrentPage.Title;
}
```

if you want to use the sender you can do the following

```
public partial class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        CurrentPageChanged += CurrentPageHasChanged;
    }

    private void CurrentPageHasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        var tabbedPage = (TabbedPage) sender;
        Title = tabbedPage.CurrentPage.Title;
    }
}
```

Or if you can elaborate on what you are trying to do exactly I can give a better answer as I do not know what it is that you are trying to do exactly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve what you want to do, at least not like this. The event behaves the way it does and as described: it is fired whenever the current page changes, also for children.

That being said, I think you should focus on implementing the functionality you want with the tools we have. I can't really deduce from your code what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want to change the title? When a tab is changed? Why not just make some kind of condition to only do it for certain pages? For example when the page is contained in the `Children` collection?

Comment: The issue i am facing, I tried to explain in updated question. I can't make condition for certain pages I can have multiple pages in app. As you said I am not able to make condition like collection containing _Child_, This is the basic thing why not available in xamarin.forms?